# What does this error message mean in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, gmail, smtplib

I made an email spam bot a while ago for fun. (Just as a test and to mess with friends) I tried to run it today and it wouldn't work. Any ideas why and how to fix? I've made sure that this API has access to my email.

> Edit: Error Message is Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Code\Spam Bot.py", line 10, in server.login('email', 'password') File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 750, in login raise last_exception File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 739, in login (code, resp) = self.auth( File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 662, in auth raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp) smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials r185-20020acadac2000000b0035173c2fddasm754089oig.51 - gsmtp')

````
e = 0

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

server.starttls()

server.login('email', 'password')
while(e < 2):
    server.sendmail('email',
                'receiver',
                'text'
                )
    e = e + 1
    print("DONE")```
````

Comment: It is self explanatory: your email address and password aren't being accepted.  Two likely causes are they are incorrect, or you have 2-factor authentication turned on (which requires an app password you need to generate).  Follow the link for debugging suggestions.

Comment: After doing some poking around I found this... "To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password."  What else do I need to sign in? I tried to let less secure apps access my account but it's no longer allowed. Then it sends me back to the page above.

Comment: Also, if there is a feature like this on something like outlook please let me know!

Comment: Try turning on 2-factor, generating an app password, and using that.

Comment: @craigb Anyway you can find a tutorial? I'm quite new to sending emails in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Username and Password not accepted.

Do to the removal of [less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) you can not use the gmail users actual password when connecting to the smtp server.

You must either enable 2fa on the account and configure an [apps password](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_u5KIeXiVI), or switch to using [Xoauth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol).